# SQL Relationships

Tags: entity-relationship

I'm using MS SQL Server 2008R2, but I believe this is database agnostic.

I'm redesigning some of my sql structure, and I'm looking for the best way to set up 1 to many relationships.

I have 3 tables, Companies, Suppliers and Utilities, any of these can have a 1 to many relationship with another table called VanInfo.

A van info record can either belong to a company, supplier or utility.

I originally had a company_id in the VanInfo table that pointed to the company table, but then when I added suppliers, they needed vaninfo records as well, so I added another column in VanInfo for supplier_id, and set a constraint that either supplier_id or company_id was set and the other was null.

Now I've added Utilities, and now they need access to the VanInfo table, and I'm realizing that this is not the optimum structure.

What would be the proper way of setting up these relationships?  Or should I just continue adding foreign keys to the VanInfo table?  or set up some sort of cross reference table.

The application isn't technically live yet, but I want to make sure that this is set up using the best possible practices.

**UPDATE:**
Thank you for all the quick responses.

I've read all the suggestions, checked out all the links.  My main criteria is something that would be easy to modify and maintain as clients requirements always tend to change without a lot of notice.  After studying, research and planning, I'm thinking it is best to go with a cross reference table of sorts named Organizations, and 1 to 1 relationships between Companies/Utilities/Suppliers and the Organizations table, allowing a clean relationship to the Vaninfo table.  This is going to be easy to maintain and still properly model my business objects.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your example I would always go for 'some sort of cross reference table' - adding columns to the VanInfo table smells.

Ultimately you'll have more joins in your SP's but I think the overhead is worth it.

Comment: I agree, after studying, scribbling all kinds of designs out on a napkin, and thinking of possible future changes, some sort of cross reference table, I believe is the optimum solution.

Answer (score 1):

When you design a database you should not think about where the primary/foreign key goes because those are concepts that doesn’t belong to the design stage. I know it sound weird but you should not think about tables as well ! (you could implement your E/R model using XML/Files/Whatever
Sticking to E/R relationship design you should just indentify your entity (in your case Company/supplier/utilities/vanInfo) and then think about what kind of relationship there is between them(if there are any). For example you said the company can have one or more VanInfo but the Van Info can belong only to one Company. We are talking about a one – to- many relationship as you have already guessed. At this point when you “convert” you design model (a one-to many relationship)  to a Database table you will know where to put the keys/ foreign keys. In the case of a one-to-Many relationship the foreign key should go to the “Many” side. In this case the van info will have a foreign keys to company (so the vaninfo table will contain the company id) . You have to follow this way for all the others tables

Have a look at the link below:

https://homepages.westminster.org.uk/it_new/BTEC%20Development/Advanced/Advanced%20Data%20Handling/ERdiagrams/build.htm

Answer (score 1):

Your database basically need normalization and I think you're database should be on its fifth normal form where you have two tables linked by one table. Please see this article, this will help you:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_normal_form

You may also want to see this, database normalization:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 1):

Consider making `Com`, `Sup` and `Util` PKs a `GUID`, this should be enough to solve the problem. However this sutiation may be a good indicator of poor database design, but to propose a different solution one should know more broad database context, i.e. that you are trying to achive. To me this seems like a `VanInfo` should be just a separate entity for each of the tables (yes, exact duplicate like `Com_VanInfo`, `Sup_VanInfo` etc), unless VanInfo isn't shared between this entities (then relationships should be inverted, i.e. `Com`, `Sup` and `Util` should contain FK for `VanInfo`).